# Force PostgreSQL clients to use SSL?

Tags: postgresql

I have configured `ssl = on` in `postgresql.conf` (and installed a certificate etcetera). Does this ensure that all clients will always connect over SSL?

(I.e. does `ssl = on` it make it impossible to connect *without* SSL encryption?)

Are there other ways to ensure that all clients always connect over SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`ssl = on` only enables the possibility of using SSL.

To ensure that all clients are using SSL, add `hostssl` lines in `pg_hba.conf`, e.g.,

```
hostssl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

and remove all `host` lines.  (Well, maybe keep the ones for `localhost`.)

If the desire is to force the client to send a certificate, then `md5` has to be changed to `cert`. e.g.,

```
hostssl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  cert
```

Answer (score 14):

No, that simply enables the use of SSL. You need to also make the appropriate changes to your [pg_hga.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, Try to avoid making connections without passwords. One of the strongest choices would be ssl (verify-full mode) + password authentication (encrypted with scram-sha-256).

Your pg_hba.conf could be like:

```
hostssl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  scram-sha-256 clientcert=verify-full
```

Answer (score 0):

The server can make sure clients connecting to it use TLS. This is done by using the `hostssl` connection type instead of `host` in the [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file.

However, this does not prevent [man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) because PostgreSQL clients by default use [`sslmode=prefer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLMODE) which means [opportunistic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_encryption). In this mode, a client does not validate the server certificate. It does not even use encryption if the server it connects to (which may be a MITM) does not offer TLS. Therefore it only prevents passive wiretapping, but not active attacks.

To really enforce secure connections, you have to make sure your clients use `sslmode=verify-full`. Another way would be the use of [certificate authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-cert.html) by setting the *`auth-method`* to `cert` in your `pg_hba.conf` file which makes sure the client connecting to the server is a known client and not a MITM. Using certificate authentication, a client connecting to a MITM may still send some login credentials to the MITM, but it won’t be possible to use those to connect to the real server.