# Can you force pgpool to require SSL connections?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

Can you force pgpool to drop non-ssl connections? I know you can with postgresql ([Force PostgreSQL clients to use SSL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8580/force-postgresql-clients-to-use-ssl)), but dropping that same syntax (hostssl instead of host) results in a hba_pool.conf syntax error.

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking at the docs, this is not possible (though it would make sense).